# How to implement Reusing Azure document client instances in c# for Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have received an error when stressing my Azure Function, it was due the 300 connections limit : https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#numerical-sandbox-limits

The solution is to use Static clients, so when the function is requested multiple times, a single client is always used, instead of a new client each time.
I'am a numb on C# and programming, so i even don't understand what to do.

Can you help me implement what is suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#documentclient-code-example). This is my code :

```
    [FunctionName("Search")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // the person objects will be free-form in structure
        List<dynamic> results = new List<dynamic>();

        // open the client's connection
        using (DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
            new Uri(endpoint),
            authKey,
            new ConnectionPolicy
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp
            }))
           {
            // get a reference to the database the console app created
                Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(
                new Database
                {
                    Id = "cloudcasegraph"
                });

            // get an instance of the database's graph

            DocumentCollection graph = await client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(
                UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("cloudcasegraph"),
                new DocumentCollection { Id = "poc-graph1" },
                new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 400 }
                );

            // Get the gremlinquery from the headers
            IEnumerable<string> headerValues = req.Headers.GetValues("gremlinquery");
            var gremlinquery = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
            //Make the query against the graph
            IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(graph, string.Format("{0}", gremlinquery));

            // iterate over all the results and add them to the list
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
                foreach (dynamic result in await query.ExecuteNextAsync())
                    results.Add(result);
        }

        // return the list with an OK response
        return req.CreateResponse<List<dynamic>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this.
I have followed this excellent article : https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/
Long-Short story : Instead of opening a new document DB connection for each execution, i open it one time.

```
// open the client's connection
        private static DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
            new Uri(endpoint),authKey,
            new ConnectionPolicy { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct, ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp });

[FunctionName("Search")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Azure Functions wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Managing-Connections) you can do something like:

```
public static class YourFunction
{
    private static Lazy<DocumentClient> lazyClient = new Lazy<DocumentClient>(InitializeDocumentClient);
    private static DocumentClient client => lazyClient.Value;
    private static DocumentCollection graph;

    private static DocumentClient InitializeDocumentClient()
    {
        // Perform any initialization here
        var uri = new Uri("example");
        var authKey = "authKey";

        var client = new DocumentClient(uri, authKey, new ConnectionPolicy
                {
                    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                    ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp
                });

        // get a reference to the database the console app created
        Database database = client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(
        new Database
        {
            Id = "cloudcasegraph"
        }).Result;

        graph = client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(
            UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("cloudcasegraph"),
            new DocumentCollection { Id = "poc-graph1" },
            new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 400 }
            ).Result;

        return client;
    }


    [FunctionName("Search")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
            TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // the person objects will be free-form in structure
            List<dynamic> results = new List<dynamic>();



            // Get the gremlinquery from the headers
            IEnumerable<string> headerValues = req.Headers.GetValues("gremlinquery");
            var gremlinquery = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
            //Make the query against the graph
            IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(graph, string.Format("{0}", gremlinquery));

            // iterate over all the results and add them to the list
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
                foreach (dynamic result in await query.ExecuteNextAsync())
                    results.Add(result);


            // return the list with an OK response
            return req.CreateResponse<List<dynamic>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);
        }
}
```